# Ruby implementing oauth2 client credentials flow

Tags: ruby, oauth-2.0, clientcredential

I'm new to Ruby and I'm trying to implement a oauth2 with client credentials flow.

I've found the "ouath2" gem, but that requires a `redirect_uri` that I don't have.
[Here is the gem](https://github.com/oauth-xx/oauth2).

Here is what I'm trying to implement

```rb
secret_id = 'this-is-a-secret-id'
token_id = 'this-is-a-token-id'
scope = 'such-a-good-scope'
grant_type = 'client_credentials'
@client = nil

# Get access token
def GetAccessToken
    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest::Post("https://awesome-page.com/oauth/token")
    request.content = {
        { "client_id" => token_id },
        { "client_secret" => secret_id }
        { 'grant_type' => grant_type },
        { 'scope' => scope}
    }

    response = request.send
    json = response.content
    accessToken = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Token>(json)
    @client = Client.new(bearer: accessToken)
end

# Refresh token
def RefreshToken
    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest::Post("https://awesome-page.com/oauth/token")
    request.content = {
        { "client_id" => token_id },
        { "client_secret" => secret_id }
        { 'grant_type' => grant_type },
        { 'refresh_token' => scope}
    }

    response = request.send
    json = response.content
    accessToken = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Token>(json)
    @client = Client.new(bearer: accessToken)
end

# End then implementing the "getting the resources with the client" part and so on...
```

Any idea how to do this, I'm getting a little bit desperate now
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you please share how you are using the methods defined above and what error you are getting? It is not clear to me how you are trying to use the `oauth2` gem. On a completely different, the convention for defining methods is to use snake case in ruby (i.e. `def get_access_token` and `def refresh_token`)

Answer (score 0):

You’re kind of going about this all wrong. With the Oauth2 gem you need to:

1. Initialise a new `Oauth2::Client` with your client ID, secret, scope, and define the token and redirect url (this is a url in your app that users logging in get sent back to. Not used for Client Credentials flow as it’s for server to server comms)
2. Call `token = client.client_credentials.get_token`. This sets token to an AccessToken it obtained.
3. Then call `token.get(‘https://your-url.com/path/to/resource’)` - or post/patch/delete.

Look at the access_token.rb file in the repo to see the methods you can call. They also take a series of params, for things like additional headers or body payload you can pass. It’s based on Faraday so you can always look up Faraday docs for help with that part.